# Solving the First-Order Homogeneous ODE $y'-\frac{1}{3x}y=\frac{x}{3y}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, absolute-value, homogeneous-equation

I wish to solve 
$$y'-\frac{1}{3x}y=\frac{x}{3y}$$
At first, rearrange and simplify to 
$$y'=\frac{x^2+y^2}{3xy}$$
which clearly indicates that it is a homogeneous differential equation.

Apply the substitution $y=ux\rightarrow y'=u'x+u$ which gives
$$u'x=\frac{1-2u^2}{3u}$$
and by integrating we get that
$$-\frac{3}{4}\ln\left| 2u^2-1\right| = \ln \left| x\right|+c$$
$$e^{-3/4\ln\left| 2u^2-1\right|} = e^{\ln \left| x\right|+c}$$ 
$$\left| 2u^2-1\right|^{-3/4}=C \left |x \right|$$
$$\left| 2u^2-1\right|=(C \left |x \right|)^{-4/3}$$
$$\left| 2u^2-1\right|=C' \left |x ^{-4/3}\right|$$
$$\left| 2u^2-1\right|=C' x ^{-4/3}$$
Now, if I choose $ 2u^2-1=C' x ^{-4/3}$ and solve for $u$ and then for $y$, I am getting the expected $y(x) = \pm\sqrt{x^2/2+C' x^{2/3}}$. But, if I choose $ 1-2u^2=C' x ^{-4/3}$, I am getting $y(x) = \pm\sqrt{x^2/2-C' x^{2/3}}$ which are not listed in the answers at least at Alpha.

How to choose between the two? Note that $C'$ is clearly positive.

Comment: In differential equations solving methods, we use $\int\dfrac{1}{x}dx=\ln x$ rather than $\int\dfrac{1}{x}dx=\ln|x|$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't solve the second case  correctly. If

$$ 1 - 2u^2 = C'x^{-4/3} $$

then

$$ u^2 = \frac12 - \bar{C}e^{-4/3} $$

Thus
$$ y = \pm \sqrt{\frac{x^2}{2} - \bar{C}x^{2/3}} $$

$\bar{C}$ is indeed positive in this case. However, the other case flips the sign on $\bar{C}$, so we can combine the two cases by replacing $\pm \bar{C} \mapsto c$, where $c$ can be positive or negative, to get the full solution

$$ y = \pm\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{2} + c x^{2/3}} $$

which is the solution given by WolframAlpha